# Mod_rewrite headache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Alright, I'm just trying to setup a simple rewrite rule for a site.
First off, in httpd.conf I have

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then in a seperate file I have this alias setup

```
Alias /vworker/ "f:/vWorker/" 

<Directory "f:/vWorker/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Alright now, so the directory of the site is

```
f:/vWorker/urlmask
```

In there I have an .htaccess file that says this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^redirect/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?redirect=$1 [L]
```

Now, what I want, is if I go to the url http://localhost/vworker/urlmask/redirect/3161513 it will actually call http://localhost/vworker/urlmask/index.php?redirect?3161513

From my point of view everything seems to be set up right, and if I put gibberish in my .htaccess file I get a server error, so I know it's reading it.

What I end up with is a page that says "Not Found. The requested URL /vworker/urlmask/redirect/94173336828903446 was not found on this server."
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you leave out the "^"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, whenever you've got an `Alias`, you're going to need a `RewriteBase` to make things work as expected.

In your case, you should have

```
RewriteBase /vworker/urlmask/
```

in the same .htaccess as your rules.

Comment: If the URL is localhost/vworker/urlmask/... and the .htaccess is in the urlmask folder, this should be the right `RewriteBase`. You can add something like `RewriteLogLevel 2` to get some logging of the rewrite process (higher numbers give more info).

Comment: Turns out I had a file called redirect.sql, so when I renamed that it worked.

Comment: But now I'm having the issue of resources not working, such as images, css, etc. It must actually look for them in the redirect folder, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It would depend on where the resources are, what their URLS look like (or should look like)... might be a different question.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks though.